# How do I use one of the standard windows icons via the Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, icons, user32, loadimage

For an app-supplied icon I  know I can use `LR_LOADFROMFILE`, `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` flags with `user32.LoadImageA`, but for now I want to use one of the standard windows supplied ones, I think they live in a win32 dll somewhere (maybe user32 itself).

How do I use one of the standard windows icons via the Win32 API?

Comment: Which icon are you looking for?

Comment: Appending a question mark into a statement doesn't make it a question. Please see [ask].

Comment: @IInspectable did you read the title?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan doesn't really matter, don't have my own right now and wanted to know how to use those that are guaranteed to be present in a standard location.

Comment: Still unclear, what you're asking. You simply load the icon the same way, but without the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag. What issue are you having? Where does your code fail? Incidentally, where is the code you are using?

Comment: The standard icons are documented in the help file for LoadIcon

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks David, it may be obvious now you've pointed out LoadIcon exists but I'm still getting to grips with the API. If you want to post that as the answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Thre is also `ExtractIcon` and `ExtractIconEx`.

Comment: There is also SHGetImageList. I am not however sure where documentation of the images loaded by that function can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`LoadIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona) to load one of the standard icons. You must pass `NULL` as the instance and the one of the predefined values `IDI_ERROR`, `IDI_QUESTION`, etc. See the documentation for the full list.